# `(a,b)` versus `(a*b)` in ocaml

Tags: ocaml, ml

It seems that only `a * b` can fit in to `_` and only `(a,b)` can fit in to `(a,_)`.

I can imagine that `a*b` is a proper type for the internal product with components `a` and `b` whereas `(a,b)` is a external product of type `a` and type `b` (just a guess)

But are there examples distinguishing the two ?

```ml
type zero = Z : zero
type 'a succ = S : 'a succ

type _ ptree1 =
  | Leaf : 'a -> ('a * zero) ptree1
  | Node : (('a * 'n) ptree1 * ('a * 'n) ptree1) -> ('a * 'n succ) ptree1

type (_, _) ptree =
  | Leaf : 'a -> ('a, zero) ptree
  | Node : (('a, 'n) ptree * ('a, 'n) ptree) -> ('a, 'n succ) ptree

(* bad
type ('a * _) ptree =
  | Leaf : 'a -> ('a, zero) ptree
  | Node : (('a, 'n) ptree * ('a, 'n) ptree) -> ('a, 'n succ) ptree
 *)
```

```ml
let rec last1 : type n a. (a * n) ptree1 -> a = function
  | Leaf x      -> x
  | Node (_, t) -> last1 t

let rec last : type n a. (a, n) ptree -> a = function
  | Leaf x      -> x
  | Node (_, t) -> last t
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type constructors have an arity in OCaml.
For instance,  in

```ml
type ('a,'b) either =
 | Left of 'a
 | Right of 'b
```

the type constructor `either` has an arity of two. And `('a,'b) either` denotes the type constructor `either` applied to two argument `'a` and `'b`. The form `('a,'b)` does not exist by itself in the language.

However, it is possible to encode type constructor with an arity of n as a type constructor of arity 1 constrained on only having a n-tuple type as an argument.
Typically, this means rewriting `either` to

```ml
type 'p either2 =
 | Left2 of 'a
 | Right2 of 'b
constraint 'p = 'a * 'b

let translation: type a b. (a*b) either2 -> (a,b) either = function
| Left2 x -> Left x
| Right2 x -> Right x
```

Here, `either2` is a type constructor of arity one, but which arguments must be a 2-tuple type.

This is the equivalent of translating a function of type `'a -> 'b -> 'c` to a function of type `'a * 'b -> 'c` at the type-level.
And another point of view is that type-level applications were written like function applications `('a,'b) either` would be written `either 'a 'b` and `('a * 'b) either2` would become `either2 ('a * 'b)`.

Without GADTs, this kind of encoding requires the use of an explicit `constraint` and they are thus not that frequent.
With GADTs, since the definition of the GADTs is free to construct its own type indices, this choice is simply more apparent. For instance, one can define an eccentric version of `either` as

```ml
type (_,_,_) either3 =
| Left3: 'a -> ('a list -> _, 'a * unit, _) either3
| Right3: 'a -> ( _ -> 'a array, _, unit * 'a) either3

let translate: type a b. (a list -> b array, a * unit, unit * b) either3 -> (a,b) either =
function
| Left3 x -> Left x
| Right3 x -> Right x
```

Here, `either3` is a type constructor of arity `3`, which stores the left and right types all over the place among its 3 argument.

Comment: can we ever observe a difference between a constructor of arity 2 taking `(a,b)` and a constructor of arity 1 taking a type tuple `(a*b)` of size 2 as type argument ?

Comment: I wonder what could prevent ocaml from writing those type level transformation by itself. Given that (_,_) applies only to the kind * of ocaml types.

Comment: At the module level, the type constructors with different arities are not compatible (in signature)? Moreover, there are multiple encoding of n-ary type constructors into unary type constructor, there is no reason to make one of this encoding canonical.